# Phone damaged in water 10 days ago but last back-up was made on computer 1 month ago. What shall I do to keep all the data when I get a new phone now?

Tags: iphone, backup, android, data

I dropped my iphone x in the sea 10 days ago and since then been using an Android phone my friend loaned me. My last backup on that iphone was made a month ago on my Macbook. I have been using Whatsapp, Wechat, emails and other Apps on that loaned Android phone. When I get a new iphone, what should I do so that I could also transfer all the data generated during this time on that Android phone onto the new iphone?

Thanks!!

Comment: You have **TWO** backups from 2 different platforms, I don't believe there is a way to shuffle all that back together, tho Apple does provide an app to migrate from Android to iOS. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196

Comment: Unless you've been doing something odd, the server controls for things like email.

Comment: Thank you Steve! This is helpful. I will try what you suggested later. But another difficulty with that loaned phone is that it is bought in China and it seems like there is something built-in there to block the access to certain websites and downloading of certain Apps. You have a great day!